# how to keep an image snapped to a border in an SVG when the browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, aspect-ratio, snap.svg

I am trying to define an html page with an svg section containing an image.
The svg viewport should occupy the whole window, and the image should be docked on one side, let's say the right down corner.
The thing is, I want the right border of my image to stick to the border of the window when my window width changed.  But the image is pushed back out of the visible area.  I do believe it is because, even if the window is resized, the viewport is not.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript">
    var paper, el;
    function init() {
        paper = Snap(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        el = paper.image("http://calibre11.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TAG-Heuer-Monaco-Cal360-1024x768.jpg", 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight).attr({
            preserveAspectRatio : "xMaxYMax meet"
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
    .svg {
        background-color: black
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do for the svg viewport and viewbox to automatically adjust to the size of the window?  Manage a window resize event?  I have tried to use percentages, without any success.

What should I do for the svg image right side to stick to the right side of the window? Same, I would want to use use percentages, but it does not work well it seems.

(I use an image inside an svg element because I want to mask it later on).

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting the svg/paper viewBox width/height to 100%, and a perserveAspectRatio on it.

Comment: Hello, thanks but the problem is the viewport, which is fixed and won't resize automatically when the window is resized:  I tried to use percentage but it does not work.  I manage to solve my problem by changing the width and height attribute of the svg/paper, and yes I used preserveAspectRatio.  Though, it was not exactly the effect I was looking for, so basically I set manually the image size and positions when the windows is resized too. Thanks for your comment.